# Python with java

Tags: java, python, jvm

Instead of using Jython, is there any way to call a Java program from Python?

This Java program contains some function and I need to give an input file to Java code and it  returns two values which I will be using in Python. So the Python program passes a filename to the Java code and the Java code will return two values for each line in that file.

For example I have the following file containg data like given below:

```
22      16050408        2       2184    T:0.938645      C:0.0613553
22      16050612        2       2184    C:0.915751      G:0.0842491
22      16050678        2       2184    C:0.94826       T:0.0517399
22      16050984        2       2184    C:0.997711      G:0.00228938
22      16051107        2       2184    C:0.94185       A:0.0581502
```

I need give a file to the Java program and it will return two values for each line of that file. So the number of lines in the file containg the above data, input to java code will be the same. I need to replace the column two with two columns.. i.e. the values returned by Java.

Please kindly help

Comment: You could create a subprocess invoking a Java program which outputs the data you need.

Comment: Are you trying to call java **program** or java **function**? You speak of the former, but the mention of Jython suggests the later.

Answer (score 2):

You can always call the java program as a command-line tool - it then does not really matter in what language the program is. For that purpose I would recommend using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. You can even pipe the input/output to your python program without using any temporary files on the filesystem. Following example runs a java app and gets its output:

```
prog = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/java", "TestClass"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print prog.stdout.read()
```

Another option, although more involved would be using [py4j](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/index.html):

> Py4J enables Python programs running in a Python interpreter to dynamically access Java objects in a Java Virtual Machine. Methods are called as if the Java objects resided in the Python interpreter and Java collections can be accessed through standard Python collection methods. Py4J also enables Java programs to call back Python objects. Py4J is distributed under the BSD license.

I think this does sound like something you are doing..

The advantage of the Py4J is that it is a more portable solution using sockets to communicate between the java and python program - you are not running JVM inside your python environment, you literally "communicate" with existing JVM instance running the py4j gateway.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/).

Here's a quote on usage from the documentation:

```
from jpype import * 
startJVM("d:/tools/j2sdk/jre/bin/client/jvm.dll", "-ea") 
java.lang.System.out.println("hello world") 
shutdownJVM()
```

This will fire up a dedicated JVM where you can run your Java code, calling it transparently from Python.

Although in your case I believe you really could just run your routine as a subprocess, also having the advantage of easy switching from Java to anything else if you would need to do so in future.

Comment: FYI `import *` is generally to be avoided as it pollutes the namespace. import the specific things you want. In examples give the full qualification to ease copy/paste errors.

Comment: @PhilH Completely agree. Just for the sake of illustration I left it in it's original condition. Although it's still kinda cool to be able to do `java.lang.System.out.println("hello world")` in Python :)